# Filtering using an indirect relationship in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, relationship

I have three tables with these relationships:
'T1'[B]<-'T2'[A] (Many to one respectively) &
'T2'[D]<-'T3'[A] (Many to one respectively)

Now imagine I want to have a report like this table:
Items of 'T2'[C] | sum('T1'[C])

I also need to filter this table by selecting some items of T3[B]. What I did was creating a Measure:
`SumByT3 = CALCULATE(SUM('T1'[C]), USERELATIONSHIP('T1'[B], 'T2'[A]), USERELATIONSHIP('T2'[D],'T3'[A]))`
(While having these relationships defined.)

Then I put a page filter on T3[B]. After that I created a table with T2[C] as axis and SumByT3 as value. But it is not working. Even if I remove the page filter.

Comment: between T1 and T2 which one is on the many side? between T2 and T3 which one is on the many side?

Comment: @smpa01 respectively.

Comment: The arrow direction is wrong then `'T1'[B]<-'T2'[A]`

Comment: Yes in Power BI the arrow indicates the direction of filter flow, not the direction of a reference to a primary key.  So here any filters on T2 and T3 should flow to T1, and you shouldn't need to change the filters in the measure at all, so just `SUM('T1'[C])`

Comment: The reason I need to use USERELATIONSHIP is that there are more than one relation between 'T1' and 'T2' in the real scenario. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: My first thought was that I should not even write second USERELATIONSHIP as there is only one relation in the right direction. But as it didn't work I tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure
which gives the SUM of all T1[C]

`{that has the same filteredT2[A] as T1[B]}`

`{filteredT2 contains all T2[D] where T2[D]=T3[A]}`

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'T1'[C] ),
    TREATAS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            CALCULATETABLE ( T2, FILTER ( T2, ( T2[D] ) IN SUMMARIZE ( T3, T3[A] ) ) ),
            T2[A]
        ),
        T1[B]
    )
)
```

The following returns T2 that only has T2[D]=T3[A]

```
Table =
CALCULATETABLE ( T2, FILTER ( T2, ( T2[D] ) IN SUMMARIZE ( T3, T3[A] ) ) )
```

Then, only unique T2[A] are extracted with

```
SUMMARIZE (
            CALCULATETABLE ( T2, FILTER ( T2, ( T2[D] ) IN SUMMARIZE ( T3, T3[A] ) ) ),
            T2[A]
        )
```

which is used inside a TREATAS which creates an inner join of T2[A] and T1[B]

Comment: Can you please explain what was my fault in understanding the logic of the problem and the way I was trying to solve it? I thought whenever I used USERELATIONSHIP, it meant a join is taking place. So there would be two joins. Then by filtering any column in the "one" side tables the result would be filtered. Is it that we cannot use relations to do chained joins and we need to CALCULATETABLE to do so?

Comment: One of the DAX conceptions leads us to believe that in order for DAX to work there must exist a relationship. Between two tables only one active relation can exist and therefore to cater to the different scenarios we keep on building inactive relationship with different surrogate key with the hope of utilizing them through `USERELATIONSHIP` if we need to activate that part. But the truth is DAX can still work without relationship - TREATAS, CONTAINS, INTERSECT. Therefore, I don't need to utilize `USERLEATIONSHIP` at all cause I can use these syntax. BTW did it give you what you needed?

Comment: I am not a big fan of `USERELATIONSHIP` and don't use that frequently, therefore I can't really asses the expression you wrote.

Comment: I agree generally that if I need to explicitly mention which relation to use, I could define the relation right there. As I was implementing @smpa01 code I found out my data source has a pattern deviation in relation between T1 and T2, T1 is not pointing to T2 index (ID). Instead it was in relation with another column. So I fixed both my code and smpa01's. Please tell me if I need to delete the post altogether. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it resolved the issue.